# Change a position based script to move folders only if the folder name exists in the text file line

Tags: powershell

I have a filetext **jd.txt** formatted in this way

```
Lanterna Verde - Le Prime Storie;(1959 10) Showcase Presents n  22;
Lanterna Verde - Le Prime Storie;(1959 12) Showcase Presents n  23;beta;
Lanterna Verde - Le Prime Storie;alfa;(1959 14) Showcase;gamma;
Batman DC;da definire;le prime avventure;
```

I have 4 folders named in this way

```
(1959 10) Showcase Presents n  22
(1959 12) Showcase Presents n  23
(1959 14) Showcase
le prime avventure
```

I use a script that make this

--> Create 2 folders called `Lanterna Verde - Le Prime Storie` and `Batman DC`
--> Moves items inside a folder structure in this simply way:

```
Lanterna Verde - Le Prime Storie
   |
   +-- (1959 10) Showcase Presents n  22
   +-- (1959 12) Showcase Presents n  23
   +-- (1959 14) Showcase
    
Batman DC
   |
   +--- le prime avventure
```

To make this I set up a script in this way

```
$sourcePath = 'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\NUOVI SCRIPTS DA CARICARE\test'
$inputFile  = Join-Path -Path $sourcePath -ChildPath 'jd.txt'
# because the title may contain invalid characters for a folder name like ':'
# create a regex to remove those if applicable
$invalid = "[{0}]" -f [RegEx]::Escape(([IO.Path]::GetInvalidFileNameChars() -join ''))

Import-Csv -Path $inputFile -Delimiter ';' -Header Title,FileName,Link | Group-Object Title | ForEach-Object {
    # combine the Title with the source path. Remove invalid characters from the Title
    $targetFolder = Join-Path -Path $sourcePath -ChildPath ($_.Name -replace $invalid)
    # if the destination folder does not already exist, create it
    if (!(Test-Path -Path $targetFolder -PathType Container)) {
        $null = New-Item -Path $targetFolder -ItemType Directory
    }
    foreach ($fileName in $_.Group.FileName) {
        $targetFile = Join-Path -Path $sourcePath -ChildPath $fileName
        if (Test-Path -Path $targetFile -PathType Container) {
            Move-Item -Path $targetFile -Destination $targetFolder -Force
        }
        else {
            Write-Warning "File '$targetFile' not found!"
        }
    }
}
```

**What is the problem?**

Script creates the folders `Lanterna Verde - Le Prime Storie` and `Batman DC` but don't move items (in this situation objects to move are other folders) within their own folders as indicated in the text file according to the specific formatting (the discriminant is the semicolon `;`)

**Note**: I can create a better jd.txt but the meaning is based on the position of the text in a particular column. What I am asking is to relax this condition and just rely on the filename present in the line
. For example, this script works good if I create a jd.txt formatted like [this](https://pastebin.com/raw/eLn9Wg37)  - if I have, for example, 3 files or 3 folders like 
first_name.part1.rar
second_name.part01.rar
 second_name.part01.rev 
this script create 2 folders: 
Citadel: Forged with Fire
Eurotrack Simulator
 and move files correctly inside them. But I need to fix for this example above

Comment: You have already asked this on StackOverflow (now deleted), where I already commented that the code you post is my answer to a [different question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66005704/9898643). It relies on the fact that the input file is solidly structured and because yours is not (fields in different columns or as you put it yourself _"just some spam text"_) the code won't work. The solution really is for you to fix the input file.

Comment: @Theo But I don't want to change the file manually. If it's a script that does this to me, then that's fine by me, but why do I have to change it first manually? That's not what I asked for. This is a different question

Answer (score 1):

You may need to add a trailing slash to your folder names because you're joining them again. Try out writing your values back to the console and see if they are actually correct, plus you can remove some of your path checking since you're using `-Force` already:

```
$csvpath = 'C:\temp\temp.csv'
$invalid = "[{0}]" -f [RegEx]::Escape(([IO.Path]::GetInvalidFileNameChars() -join ''))
$sourcePath = 'C:\temp\'

Import-Csv C:\temp\temp.csv -Header Title,FileName,Link -Delimiter ';' | 
  Group-Object Title | 
  Foreach {

    # I prefer to add a trailing slash to folder names
    $TargetFolder = Join-Path -Path $sourcePath -ChildPath (($_.Name -replace $invalid)+'\')

    # We don't have to create the new folders, because -Force will create them for us
    Foreach ($fileName in $_.Group.FileName) {
      $ValidFileName = $filename -replace $invalid
      $targetFile = Join-Path -Path $sourcePath -ChildPath $fileName

      # Write your values to the console - Make sure the folder is what it should be
      Write-Output "Moving '$targetFile' to '$TargetFolder'"
      Move-Item $targetFile $TargetFolder -Force -WhatIf
    }
  }
```

So the output looks like:

```
Moving 'C:\temp\(1959 10) Showcase Presents n  22' to 'C:\temp\Lanterna Verde - Le Prime Storie\'
What if: Performing the operation "Move File" on target "Item: C:\temp\(1959 10) Showcase Presents n  22 Destination: C:\temp\Lanterna Verde - Le Prime Storie\".
```

Comment: mm.. I think that are some problems. For example, `beta`, `alfa`, `da definire` they are not folders that exist, it is just some spam text between those 4 real folders that should be moved, see what I mean: https://imgur.com/BOh0UiX.png ---> so, I look in console and it return me "cannot find path because it does not exist" --- > https://imgur.com/hwIWSYi.png -- Why this error appears when the folders to be moved would be only those really present?

Comment: I try to test but it doesn't move folders but only write in console *Moving*... *to*..

Comment: _"You may need to add a trailing slash to your folder names because you're joining them again"_. Nope, no need becaus the joining is done with `Join-Path` cmdlet that takes care of it.

Comment: Also, `$targetFile = Join-Path -Path $sourcePath -ChildPath $fileName` should be `$targetFile = Join-Path -Path $TargetFolder -ChildPath $fileName`

Comment: @Theo ok, but `Foreach ($fileName in $_.Group.FileName) {
      $ValidFileName = $filename -replace $invalid
      $targetFile = Join-Path -Path $TargetFolder -ChildPath $fileName` it is a partial solution because here the problem it is add a `if` condition to splitting the files into 3 culumns and only reading from one and match folder names located in C:\temp\ and folder names in a text file. if it is a formatted problem script should change the formatting or read as a new formatted text to satisfy the request I think

Comment: @AlexDoc No, as I tried to explain earlier, since the input csv file is inconsistent, you cannot use that in this way. The folder to move to is not always in the same column, so any code trying to use that as input will hit the problem of the value not corresponding to the folder you want to move to. It simply reads garbage ("spam") where it expects the folder name.  If you do not provide a valid, reliable input file, the the only way to do it is by examining **all** fields for **every** row to find if that field contains a target folder name you can use. That means a LOT of `Test-Path` lines

Comment: @Theo ok, but this "Test-Path" lines will the Powershell console generate them, is correct? yes, I need a script that **examining all fields for every row** *to find if that field contains a target folder name you can use*.. **yes**, it's that I want...